# how to find an element in array of object with streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have object list.

```
List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
```

every Item has 1 arrayList

```
public class Item {
    private String id;
    private List<Property> propertyList;
}
```

Property has key and value as String

```
public class Property {
    private String key;
    private String value;
}
```

I want to create a stream on Itemlist and get the new list which contains

Item.propertyList.key.equals("Test") as a new list.

Comment: You mean *any* `propertyList` element where `key.equals("Test")`?

Comment: `itemList.stream()
                .filter(item -> item.getPropertyList().stream().anyMatch(property -> property.getKey().equals("")))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: yes, if any Item property key is Test, stream will add it into a new list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
itemList.stream()
          .filter(item -> item.getPropertyList()
                         .stream().anyMatch(property -> property.getKey().equals("Test")))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4):

Bit cleaner than Hadi's suggestion:

```
itemList.stream()
   .filter(item -> item.getPropertyList()
          .stream().map(Property::getKey).anyMatch("Test"::equals))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: how can I add AND condition between properties. ex: if property.getKey = TEST and propery.getvalue =FOO and property.getKey = BAR and property.getavalue = XX

Comment: @sakirow The way I've written it, you can't. Use the way Hadi showed, with logical `&&`

Comment: @sakirow Sounds more like a key, value lookup with something like a `Map` in use rather  than a separate entity.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a list of matching Property classes, you can do it with flatMap:

```
final List<Property> collect = itemList.stream()
            .flatMap(item -> item.getPropertyList().stream())
            .filter(property -> "Test".equals(property.getKey()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Good try, but do notice that this maps to `Property` objects while the OP expects to collect back `Items`.